# json list filter contains given text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list

```
var jsonList = [
   {
      "id": "one",
      "pId": "nosearch",
      "cId": "searchc"
   },
   {
      "id": "two",
      "pId": "product1",
      "cId": "searchc"
   },
   {
      "id": "three",
      "pId": "product2",
      "tId": "searcht"
   }
]
```

I want to get the list of all items containing the given text.
For example, if i search for 'search', it should return all the items, If i search product, it should return second and third item.

any function like search(jsonList, searchText) will achieve this?

Comment: means in any field as value ?

Comment: yes. it should match any of the values of the attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var jsonList = [{
    "id": "one",
    "pId": "nosearch",
    "cId": "searchc"
}, {
    "id": "two",
    "pId": "product1",
    "cId": "searchc"
}, {
    "id": "three",
    "pId": "product2",
    "tId": "searcht"
}]
function search(jsonList, searchText) {
    return jsonList.filter(function(x) {
        for (var i in x) {
            if (x[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1) return x;
        }
    })
}
console.log(search(jsonList, 'search'))
```

Comment: some more attribute can be added or removed at anytime. So we cannot tell pId, id, tId etc.

Comment: Looks great. how to make it case insensitive search?

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer you have to use `toLowerCase()` . i have updated my answer

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Regex is more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Search an object:

```
var obj = {
     'one':1,
    'two': 1,
    'three': 2
}

console.log(matches(obj, 1));

function matches(obj, str){
    var ret = new Array();
    for(var key in obj){
         if(obj[key] == str){
              ret.push(key);
         }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqmxqkcz/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (**Prototype way Case Insensitive**):

```
var data = [{
    "id": "one",
        "pId": "nosearch",
        "cId": "searchc"
}, {
    "id": "two",
        "pId": "product1",
        "cId": "searchc"
}, {
    "id": "three",
        "pId": "product2",
        "tId": "searcht"
}]

Array.prototype.find = function (str) {
    return this.filter(function (elem) {
        for (var i in elem) {
            var strRegExPattern = '\\b' + str + '\\b';
            var pattern = new RegExp(strRegExPattern, "i")
            if (elem[i].match(pattern)) {
                return this;
            }
        }
    });
}

console.log(data.find('searchc'));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh1at0rj/1/)